# Understanding the error : "Error: ng:areq "

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I have created a sample program in ionic. Here Im creating a variable i.e
(var itemCheck=angular.module('Shop',['ionic','starter.controllers']);) in app.js of ionic file:

app.js

```
var itemCheck=angular.module('Shop',['ionic','starter.controllers']);
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {]
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {....});
```

and Im using the created variable in my controller.js inorder to access the html page :

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
       .controller('AppCtrl',function ($scope, $ionicModal,$timeout,$ionicHistory) {
        // });

        itemCheck.controller('fruit', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.home = function () {
              window.location = "#/menu.html"
            }
```

html page:

```
<ion-content ng-app="Shop" ng-controller="fruit">
    <header>
```

but on execution Im get error which states that

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fruit' is not a function, got undefined
```

what it the meaning of this error and why does it states that 'fruit' is not a function. And I don't want to create a separate .js files

Comment: Shouldn't ng-controller="AppCtrl"

Comment: You have defined a controller inside an other controller. Try separating them.

Comment: @RaviTeja both are different controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.js should be like this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
 .run(function($ionicPlatform) {].....
```

controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
   .controller('fruit',function ($scope, $ionicModal,$timeout,$ionicHistory) {
 $scope.home = function () {
          window.location = "#/menu.html"
        }
    // })
```

html template

```
<ion-content ng-app="Shop" ng-controller="fruit">
```

You are doing it wrong. You should read more . Thanks

Comment: I already tried what you have explained and  it was a working but my senior develper told to use in the way I have described above. So thats why I posted it. @Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: This doesn'make any sense. only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead.

Comment: Here see this .. maybe it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/j5jzsppv/